# Findallbyattributes With Related Model

Tags: yii

I'm trying to do a `findAllByAttributes` using a related model column as one of the criteria, but I keep getting a `CDbException` stating `the column cannot be found`.

Here's my model Relationship:

```
public function relations() {
  return array(
    'MetaData' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProjectMeta', 'wbse_or_io'),
  );
}
```

And here's my attempted query:

```
$listing = ProjectIndex::model()->with('MetaData')
  ->findAllByAttributes(array(
    'report_date'=>$reportDate,
    'MetaData.cost_centre'=>$costCentre
  )
);
```

From what I've read through Google/StackOverflow/these forums, I should be able to reference the cost_centre column in the MetaData relationship. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Table "tbl_project_index" does not have a column named "MetaData.cost_centre"
```

How do I reference the related table column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this out

```
$listing = ProjectIndex::model()->with(
    'MetaData'=>array(
        'condition'=>'cost_centre = :cost_centre', 
        'params'=>array('cost_centre'=>$costCentre))
   )
   ->findAllByAttributes(array('report_date'=>$reportDate));
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't know you could add conditions/params to the 'with' clause

Answer (score 1):

The attributes in the attributes array cannot be for the related models. You can look at the source for [`findAllByAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes) for a better explanation. You can, however, pass the related attribute as a condition string or `CDbCriteria` array, in addition to Alex's answer.

```
$listing = ProjectIndex::model()->with('MetaData')->findAllByAttributes(
    array('report_date'=>$reportDate),
    'cost_centre = :cost_centre',
    array(':cost_centre'=> $costCentre)
);
```

Or

```
$listing = ProjectIndex::model()->with('MetaData')->findAllByAttributes(
    array('report_date'=>$reportDate),
    array(
        'condition' =>'cost_centre = :cost_centre',
        'params'=>array(':cost_centre'=> $costCentre)
    ),
);
```

Comment: Ah, couldn't find a decent explanation as to why the conditions needed to be seperated.  Thanks